# For Loop won't exit in Javascript, looping infinitely

Tags: javascript, for-loop

My script is causing the browser to freeze and asking me to stop the script. Using firebug I can see the for loop is endlessly looping and not making any progress. Here's the loop:

```
for (var x = 1; x < 7; x++) {
    var y = x; //to stop the value of x being altered in the concat further down
    var questionidd = "mcq_question_id";
    console.log("1 = " + questionidd);
    var questionid = questionidd.concat(y); // mcq_question_id$ctr the question number
    console.log("2 = " + questionid);
    var mcqid = form[questionid].value; // the questions id on db
    console.log("3 = " + mcqid);

    var answerr = "mcq_question";
    var answer = answerr.concat(y); // mcq_question$ctr the questions chosen answer
    var chosenanswer = form[answer].value; // the answers value
    console.log("4 = " + chosenanswer);
    var amp = "&";
    var equal = "=";
    var questionide = questionid.concat(equal); // "mcq_question_id$ctr="
    var questionida = amp.concat(questionide); // "&mcq_question_id$ctr="
    var answere = amp.concat(answer, equal); // "&mcq_question$ctr="
    if (x = 1) {
        send.push(questionide, mcqid, answere, chosenanswer);
    }
    else {
        send.push(questionida, mcqid, answere, chosenanswer);
    }
}
```

Update - Fixed! Silly mistakes are the worst

Comment: your if (x = 1) should be if (x == 1)

Answer (score 6):

```
if (x = 1) {
```

should be

```
if (x === 1) {
```

The `===` operator *compares* while the assignment operator `=` *assigns*. Many people make this mistake. :)

When the first loop runs, it sets `x` to zero, and does so infinitely until the process is terminated. That's why the loop doesn't stop.

Comment: `===` is better still. There is hardly ever a case where `==` is the right solution.

Comment: I wouldn't say hardly ever a case but yes in most cases `===` is the better operator rather than `==`

Comment: @StuartWakefield `==` means you're unsure of the actual data-type of your variable (ex: String vs Number, or String vs Boolean). This is (in my experience) always caused by some laziness elsewhere - either in your own code or some 3rd party library or service that you're using.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen I'm fully aware that `==` is a type coerced equality comparison and in most cases that is not what you want, but there are occasionally legitimate uses for it.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen, actually I'm trying to think about a use that would be better to use a type coerced comparison and... I got nothing. I concede my argument.

Comment: I wouldn't say hardly ever either. == comes in handy occasionally. Sometimes you're being fed JSON that doesn't consistently indicate absence of value. So it might be null or 0 or an empty string. Sometimes you might get a number as a string or as a number. I usually prefer normalizing and then === in simpler cases but == makes sense often enough.

Answer (score 5):

`if (x = 1) {` should be `if (x === 1) {`

Consider switching to an IDE that catches simple programming errors like this.

Comment: Pardon my beginnerisms, but what's IDE?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment basically whatever program you use to write your code with (such as Notepad++, NetBeans, Eclipse or PHPStorm). Good ones perform some simple 'code analysis' and they _will_ catch this bug.

Comment: I see, I'm using the inbuilt code-editor from my cpanel - not the best. I'll get Notepad++ probably, thanks for the answer, saved me many more hours of cluelessness

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you should have "if (x == 1)" instead of "if (x = 1)".

Your code repeatedly sets x to the value 1, rather than checking that it is equivalent to 1.